# User flair image issue on hover

Tags: bug, design, user-card, performance

When hovering a user's image and their flair shows up (ex: on any review page or on a question where someone other than the OP has most recently edited the question), the flair is requested after the image is hovered. It requests a larger sized image and the other flair information *every* time that the image is hovered.

If the image loads quickly (*before* the transition finishes), it starts out behind the rest of the object then pops to the front after the rest of the flair is done animating. [Here's a GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBcaV.gif) of the issue, though it's easier to see if you test it yourself.

[image: image load before flair]

Also, if the image loads *after* the transition finished, it won't be visible often times the flair will show and the image will pop on it once it's done being loaded.

[image: image load after flair]

This is, of course, dependent on the user's current connection and the response time of the server because it deals with the load time of the image.

This is true testing on the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer on Windows 8 across multiple computers.

This bug is still here (20 September 2015) after the profile redesign.

Comment: No repro with Chrome here.

Comment: I reproduced this issue on Chrome (W7), [see gif here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aBcaV.gif)

Comment: @Billy sorry but I can't see any problem with that. This is the expected behavior and it's not behind anything. If you mean the animation it bit "laggy" it's really a minor thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The gif is a bit more laggy than when it actually happens, but you can see the image being behind the other in one frame of each hover in the gif

Comment: Think I see, but it's really minor and in my personal opinion not something worth spending any time on. I thought you meant the screenshot you posted is the final result of hovering.

Comment: I see myself in the first image. :)

Comment: I'm rather disappointed that you don't have a flair yourself to enable easy testing :P

Comment: @Bakabaka Embedded flair doesn't work the same way so I can't put it in the question itself - it has to be flair that is shown on hover. So if someone were to edit my post that had flair capabilities on hover it would work, but I alone can't do it

Comment: Re your edit: user card is not part of profile page, the redesign it not relevant.